# Resizing an icon doesn't show on GUI

Tags: python, icons, pyqt5

I am trying to make my GUI icon go bigger.
I tried this:

```
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Logo1.png'))
    MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128,128))
```

When 'Logo1.png' is 128x128

When I change numbers SetIconSize line, like this:

```
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500,500))
```

It doesn't show on my GUI.

My questions are:

- Does this happen because I need my logo to be smaller something like 28X28?
- If I need a specific size, what size is it and how do I make my logo this size?
- Even if I do need a specific size, why wont setIconSize change my icon size?

Answer (score 0):

The [`iconSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#iconSize-prop) property documentation of QMainWindow explains that:

> [The] size of toolbar icons in this mainwindow.

As you can see, it has nothing to do with the [`windowIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop).

It is up to the underlying OS and its window manager to decide the size of the icon, whether its shown in the window decoration (tipically in the title bar), the task manager/window switcher or anything else, and you don't have any control over it through Qt.

The only "exception" is when drawing *client-side* windows: windows for which the whole decoration is drawn by the program (the title bar with its system buttons and icon, the frame around the window, etc.).
That is, though, something that is usually discouraged as it's hard to achieve without facing various difficulties (both with drawing and interaction); it also makes the window appearance inconsistent with the whole system and could also create issues with accessibility for visually impaired people.